# Dependency tree from spring batch configuration

Tags: spring, spring-batch

Having a spring job definition:

```
<job id="footballJob">
    <!-- Step bean details ommitted for clarity -->
    <step id="playerload" next="gameLoad"/>
    <step id="gameLoad" next="playerSummarization"/>
    <step id="playerSummarization"/>
</job>
```

Can I progmatically figure out the order of steps to execute?

Answer (score 1):

Steps will execute in order that you listed in your example.

In case you'd like to **specify the order** you can do:

```
<job id="job">
    <step id="stepA" parent="s1" next="stepB" />
    <step id="stepB" parent="s2" next="stepC"/>
    <step id="stepC" parent="s3" />
</job>
```

In case you'd like a non sequential step execution / **conditional flow**, you can do:

```
<job id="job">
    <step id="stepA" parent="s1">
        <next on="*" to="stepB" />
        <next on="FAILED" to="stepC" />
    </step>
    <step id="stepB" parent="s2" next="stepC" />
    <step id="stepC" parent="s3" />
</job>
```

In order to **control the flow programmatically**, depending on `ExitStatus`, you can inject your own `decider`:

```
public class MyDecider implements JobExecutionDecider {
    public FlowExecutionStatus decide(JobExecution jobExecution, StepExecution stepExecution) {
        if (someCondition) {
            return "FAILED";
        }
        else {
            return "COMPLETED";
        }
    }
}
```

In the job configuration, a "decision" tag will specify the decider to use as well as all of the transitions:

```
<job id="job">
    <step id="step1" parent="s1" next="decision" />

    <decision id="decision" decider="decider">
        <next on="FAILED" to="step2" />
        <next on="COMPLETED" to="step3" />
    </decision>

    <step id="step2" parent="s2" next="step3"/>
    <step id="step3" parent="s3" />
</job>

<beans:bean id="decider" class="com.MyDecider"/>
```

**EDIT**:

If you are looking to get a `dependency graph`, you can just use [Spring Tool Suite](http://www.dotkam.com/2010/04/06/spring-batch-quick-start/) to visualize the flow, here is a [simple example](http://wordpress.transentia.com.au/wordpress/2009/06/16/springsource-toolsuite-21-supports-spring-batch/).

Comment: Thanks, but the question is how can I *progmatically* figure out which is the order of the steps (or in other words, I am interested in the dependency graph)

Answer (score 1):

> Can I progmatically figure out the order of steps to execute?

by taking your question literally there are some options:

- use [Spring Tool Suite](http://www.springsource.com/developer/sts) afaik it can display job flows
- parse job.xml by yourself, you could even use a spring batch job which would be quite funny
- try to grok the complete batch setup process, start with [spring.handlers](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-core/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.handlers) and [CoreNamespaceHandler.java](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/xml/CoreNamespaceHandler.java), you can overwrite it by your needs

  - [SimpleFlow.java](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/core/job/flow/support/SimpleFlow.java) should be sufficient

i would go with a simple xml parser